# A recurrence relation for the number of n-digit binary sequences without the "101"

Tags: combinatorics

Find a recurrence relation for $a_n$, which is the number of n-digit binary sequences **without** the sub-sequence "101". I know that $a_1=2$, $a_2=4$, $a_3=7$, $a_4=12$, but what is the general relation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binary sequences of length $n$ can only be formed by

- Preceding a length $n-1$ sequence with a $0$
- Preceding a length $n-2$ sequence with $10$ or $11$ such that the second digit matches the third digit of the new sequence. E.g. $000\mapsto \boxed{10}000$ and $100\mapsto \boxed{11}100$.
- Preceding a length $n-4$ sequence with $1100$

Hence we have the recurrence
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-4}$$
which gives
$$a_n=2, 4, 7, 12, 21, 37, 65, 114, 200, 351, 616, 1081, 1897,\dots$$

Comment: Curiously, the closed form of this recurrence relation seems to be $a(n) = F_n - 1$ ([OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000071)).

Comment: @PeterForeman it is wrong because $a_5=21$, please check carefully because there are repeated case.

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio Yes, sorry I've corrected it. This problem also appears on the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A005251) where it is stated as avoiding "$010$" instead.

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated He got this from my incorrect answer.